# org: move point to beginning of an item

Tags: org-mode, motion

When in org-mode, how to move point to the beginning of the current item? (in similar fashion like `back-to-indentation`)

*Example*:
Imagine following org buffer content

```
* headline
  - [ ] Z this is an longer item | (Point) is here. And here is some more text.
  - [X] it should work with that line too!
  - and with that one also
```

With point at location `|`, in the middle of that item. .oO(or even at the beginning of that line)
How can I easily move point to right before the letter `Z`?

I always jump around that location before I finaly hit it (i.e `C-a` `M-f` `M-b` or even `C-a` `M-f` `M-f` `M-b`) this is somewhat cumbersome..

Comment: FWIW, `C-a` works for me in all three cases (the cursor is on Z - or i or a - and the point is just before it, between the space and the first letter of the item) - Org mode version 9.3.4 (release_9.3.4-211-gb694c2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider to customize variable `org-special-ctrl-a/e`.  Possibly that will ease your flow.

From the documentation.  Note in particular the "item" part.

> When t, ‘C-a’ will bring back the cursor to the beginning of the
>   headline text, i.e. after the stars and after a possible TODO keyword.
>   In an item, this will be the position after bullet and check-box, if
>   any.  When the cursor is already at that position, another ‘C-a’ will
>   bring it to the beginning of the line.

You can also consider the other documented values for `org-special-ctrl-a/e`.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer is correct. I just wanted to add for posterity (and i'm not venerable enough to add comments) that for me and some other users enabling `visual-line-mode` remaps the relevant keys and so prevents `org-special-ctrl-a/e` from having any effect.

Remapping `C-a` and `C-e` with something like:

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-map "\C-a" 'org-beginning-of-line)
(define-key org-mode-map "\C-e" 'org-end-of-line)
```

or your preferred way of doing it, should get it going though.

Found it in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/fjku3d/visual_line_mode_conflicts_with_orgspecialctrlae/)